# Xerox Parc and the three-button mouse

Tags: mouse, gui, xerox-alto

The original GUI invented at Xerox Parc, used a three-button mouse.

What did each of the three buttons do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the Alto, the buttons’ functions vary with the program currently being used and the location of the cursor. The [Users’ Handbook](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/xerox/alto/Alto_Users_Handbook_Sep79.pdf) describes the functions in the default applications, using colours for the buttons: red for the left button (or top button), yellow for the middle button, blue for the right button (or bottom button).

In *Bravo*, the text document editor, the buttons are used as follows:

- in the left-hand part of the screen, red and blue scroll up and down respectively, and yellow opens a page;
- in the document, red selects a single character, yellow selects a word, and blue extends the selection (using characters or words depending on what’s already been selected) — this is somewhat similar to Emacs’ mark and point;
- in the “line bar” (between the scroll bar and the text area), yellow selects a paragraph, and blue extends the selection;
- with the “Window” command, blue creates a new window (with a new document), yellow splits the current window (giving two views of the current document), red moves the window;
- with the “Kill” command, red kills a window and gives its space to the window above, blue to the window below, and yellow clears the window but doesn’t kill it.

In *Laurel*, the messaging program:

- when invoking commands, red invokes a command potentially with confirmation, blue invokes a command with implicit confirmation, and yellow cancels some commands;
- in the scroll bar, red and blue work as in *Bravo*, and yellow moves around within sections (the scroll bar is somewhat more complex than their modern incarnations);
- in the message list, red and blue select messages;
- etc.